# How to remove a string from each element from an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an Array:

```
arr1 = ["gbt100", "gbt1130", "gbt12300", "gbt104230"]
```

How can I remove the "gbt" string from each of the elements?

Comment: Please read the docs on [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods. What have you tried?

Comment: `arr1.join(',').replace(/gbt/g, '').split(',')`

Comment: I've read about the foreach and filter methods. I just don't know how to apply it.

Comment: @PAyTEK You want to create a new array with the same elements of the old array, but transformed in a way. This means you need `map`, not `filter`, not `forEach`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Xufox!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `map` method by passing a *callback* function as an argument which is applied for every item from your given array.

Also, you need to use  `replace` method in order to remove the `gbt` string.

```js
arr1 = ["gbt100", "gbt1130", "gbt12300", "gbt104230"]
arr1 = arr1.map(elem => elem.replace("gbt", ""));
console.log(arr1);
```

Another approach is to pass a regex as the first argument for the `replace` method.

```js
arr1 = ["gbt100", "gbt1130", "gbt12300", "gbt104230"]
arr1 = arr1.map(elem => elem.replace(/gbt/g, ""));
console.log(arr1);
```

If you want to remove all the *alphabetical* chars just change the regex expression inside `replace` method.

```
arr1 = arr1.map(elem => elem.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, ""));
```

Comment: @Xufox, what if array is like gbt567, abg455, ytu456 ?

Comment: @akhilaravind you mean to remove all alphabetic characters then use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of gbt to replace all alphabets

Comment: @akhilaravind Don't make up scenarios OP hasn't asked for, otherwise you end up answering questions nobody asked. If OP states the values to remove could be different and gives the exact specifications, then we can tailor solutions around it. Otherwise your scenario is out of scope.

Comment: @Nagaraju i have answered below

Comment: @xufox yes I was correcting that

Comment: @akhilaravind why do you want to answer that OP did'nt ask about?

Comment: @akhilaravind, if you want to remove all aphabetic chars you can look at the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Array.Map` and for each of the item using `substring`

```
const arr1 = ["gbt100", "gbt1130", "gbt12300", "gbt104230"]

const newArr = arr1.map(x=>x.substring(3, x.length))

console.log(newArr)
```